# How to define 'mode' in typeScript for the VueRouter

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-router

I 'm new to TypeScript and ran into this issue:

```js
export default function ({ store }) {
  const Router = new VueRouter({
    scrollBehavior: () => ({ x: 0, y: 0 }),
    routes,

    // Leave these as they are and change in quasar.conf.js instead!
    // quasar.conf.js -> build -> vueRouterMode
    // quasar.conf.js -> build -> publicPath
    mode: process.env.VUE_ROUTER_MODE,
    base: process.env.VUE_ROUTER_BASE
  })
```

The `mode` is underlined saying
[image]

What is the correct way to avoid this error? I found a [similar issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/3019) but it might not be related at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mode` only accepts the following values of the following type:

`'hash' or(|) 'history' | abstract' | undefined`

The type of `process.env.VUE_ROUTER_MODE` is `string | undefined`

Since these types are different, typescript will complain that you can't assign any string, when only specific values are allowed.

Without knowing what `process.env.VUE_ROUTER_MODE` is, you will have to 'cast' it to this type, e.g.

```
mode: process.env.VUE_ROUTER_MODE as 'hash' | 'history' | 'abstract' | undefined
```

If `process.env.VUE_ROUTER_MODE` can be of another value, it might be helpful to write a helper function that checks the value first.